# Multi-variable non-convex optimization problem where the problem is convex if one variable is fixed

Tags: convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a non-convex optimization problem in the form

$$
\begin{align}
& \min{f(x,y)} \\
& \text{s.t. } h(x,y) \le 0
\end{align}
$$

I cannot derive a closed form solution. However, if I assume $y$ is constant, then the problem becomes convex and I can derive a closed form solution for $x$ as a function of $y$, i.e,

$$
\begin{align}
x^*(y) = \; & \arg \min_{x}{f(x,y)} \\
& \text{s.t. } h(x,y) \le 0
\end{align}
$$

Now, let's assume I can find the global optimal solution of the original problem somehow (numerially) and is denoted by $x_\text{opt}$ and $y_\text{opt}$. Are the following statement and the correspodning proof correct?

$$
x_\text{opt} = x^*(y_\text{opt})
$$

Proof:

By definition we have
$$
f(x_\text{opt},y_\text{opt}) \le f(x,y) \quad \forall x,y \quad \text{s.t.} \quad h(x,y) \le 0
$$
and therefore,
$$
f(x_\text{opt},y_\text{opt}) \le f(x^*(y_\text{opt}),y_\text{opt}).
$$
Also, we have
$$
f(x^*(y),y) \le f(x,y) \quad \forall x,y \quad \text{s.t.} \quad h(x,y) \le 0 
$$
Therefore, we can write
$$
f(x^*(y_\text{opt}),y_\text{opt}) \le f(x_\text{opt},y_\text{opt}).
$$
Consequently,

$$
f(x^*(y_\text{opt}),y_\text{opt}) = f(x_\text{opt},y_\text{opt})
$$
and
$$
x^*(y_\text{opt}) = x_\text{opt}.
$$

Comment: The fact that the problem is not convex does not mean that you cannot find an explicit solution in general. It would be better that you post the actual problem in order to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. You're saying that you are able to obtain $x(y)$ such that $f(x(y),y)=\min\{f(x,y):h(x,y)\le 0,x\in\mathcal X\}$ (for fixed $y$) and you want to know if $\min_{\mathrm{s.t.} h(x(y),y)\le 0} f(x(y),y)=\min_{\mathrm{s.t.} h(x,y)\le 0} f(x,y)$ (the former only minimized over $y$, the latter over $(x,y)$), correct?

Comment: Added more math to explain in more details. Appreciate any tips.